# Optimizing a user retention query

Tags: postgresql, optimization

I'm trying to automatically calculate a table for user retention, so that the end result is something like:

```
Week | %
0    | 100
1    | 50
2    | 35
```

For now I'm not bothering with the % and just trying to get a count of users, i.e. users that came back on week 1, week 2, etc.

I have an `accounts` table and an `action` table. Currently I don't have indexes in either of these. Both have a `user_email` that stores the associated user, and both have a `timestamp` field that's a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` - for `accounts` this is the account creation date and for `action` it's the timestamp of the action.

The two tables are currently super simple:

```
accounts Table:
timestamp  | timestamp with time zone
user_email |character varying
```

```
action Table:
timestamp  | timestamp with time zone
user_email |character varying
```

That's it, no keys or anything else.

I managed to piece together a query that seems to do this calculation:

```
WITH weeks AS (
    SELECT (n || 'week')::interval as week from generate_series(0, 3) AS n
)
SELECT 

    week,

    (SELECT count(*) FROM accounts WHERE user_email IN 
        (SELECT user_email FROM action
            WHERE age(action.timestamp, accounts.timestamp) >= week 
            AND age(action.timestamp, accounts.timestamp) < week + '1 week'::interval)) 
            AS "Returning Users"

FROM weeks;
```

The output here is something like:

```
week    | Returning Users
0 days  |  100
7 days  |  50
14 days |  35
21 days |  25
```

The thing is, this takes super long to calculate (with 1300 users and about 100000 actions it takes a few minutes). I'm also convinced there's a more efficient way to calculate this, or that I can at least add indexes somewhere.

Unfortunately my SQL knowledge is quite limited and after looking around for a while I'm still not sure where to start. I think I can add indexes to the `timestamp` columns? And I'm not sure my way of checking if timestamps fall in certain ranges is correct.

Comment: Please have a look at: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: How exactly are the tables `action` and `accounts` linked? Is there any foreign key between them? It would be easier if you added the `CREATE TABLE` statements for both tables and some sample data (e.g. as INSERT statements)

Comment: Sorry, should've specified. But they aren't linked together at all, neither table has any keys/indexes. They're just two tables, each having a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column and a `VARCHAR` column. And I simply make the assumption that the `user_email` column in the two tables will sometimes have matching values.

Comment: I am trying to move some of our logs from a text-based (JSON) format into a database format, hence the current simplicity.

Comment: So those two tables are linked through the `user_email` column

Comment: Yes, currently not with a foreign key but just an assumption that the `user_email` column in `action` will match the `user_email` column of some row in `accounts`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to tell how your tables are linked together, but I think the following should be more efficient:

```
WITH weeks AS (
  SELECT make_interval(weeks => n) as week 
  from generate_series(0, 3) AS n
)
SELECT week, 
       count(x.user_email) as "Returning Users"
FROM weeks
  LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT act.user_email, age(act.timestamp, acc.timestamp) as diff
     FROM accounts acc
       JOIN action act on act.user_email = acc.user_email
  ) x ON x.diff >=  week and diff < week + '1 week'::interval
FROM weeks
GROUP BY week;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked like a charm! Runs very quickly on my current dataset. (Since one user in `accounts` can correspond to multiple rows in `actions` I had to tweak the `SELECT` to be `count(distinct x.user_email)`)